# How to add dynamic custom column in UI component

Tags: magento2, custom, uicomponent, custom-column-grid, ui-grid

I have configured UI component columns in the admin grid and it's working fine. I need to add custom columns dynamically.

For example we can add custom column in **`__prepareColumns`** **function** in Block layout

My question is, will add a custom column in the UI component approach

**UI component XML:**

```
<column name="custom_column" class="Simple\Test\Ui\Component\User\Column\CustomColumns">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <!--item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item-->
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Column</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Simple_Test/js/grid/columns/customcolumns</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Comment: did you found any solution for adding dynamic columns in grid using ui component

Comment: Not yet. Tried few approach, not suitable. So used with block __prepareColumns approach

Comment: Any solution? Thanks in advance